# Debug Knockout js variable values within View file

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

Can I debug the below mentioned code on *.cshtml file ? I have used knockout js as my client side java script library.

```
<div data-bind="ifnot: book()">
        <div>
            <h2>Add New Book</h2>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input data-bind="value: $root.Name" type="text" title="Name" />
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="publisher">Publisher</label>
            <input data-bind="value: $root.Publisher" type="text" title="Publisher" />
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="price">Price</label>
            <input data-bind="value: $root.Price" type="text" title="Price" />
        </div>
        <br />
        <div>
            <button data-bind="click: $root.create">Save</button>
            <button data-bind="click: $root.reset">Reset</button>

        </div>
    </div>
```

On above code I need to check the values of say "book() or $root.Name ,etc".Can I do that ?

**UPDATE**:On Fire bug

[image]

Comment: There is an extension for Chrome: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/knockoutjs-context-debugg/oddcpmchholgcjgjdnfjmildmlielhof?hl=en which allows to debug knockout bindings.

Comment: @nemesv WOW!! Absolutely brilliant.Thanks a lot for the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the @nemesv link I did small R&D about this.Below I have mentioned the way you can find the KO binding values of the DOM elements.Hope this will help someone in future.

Link for the Extension : [KnockoutJs Context Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/knockoutjs-context-debugg/oddcpmchholgcjgjdnfjmildmlielhof)

The way you can find the KO Values on DOM elements.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use client side debugging. Either use a developer toolbar (opened with <kbd>F12</kbd> in most browsers) or use [Visual Studio Client Script debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/7seh8d72.aspx).

Comment: Actually this is not a script file.For js debugging I am using Fire bug.But my problem is how to debug KO values withing my *.cshtml file?

Comment: Hmm, I don't understand. A `cshtml` file doesn't have any values within it, it's just a razor view template (plus: the code you posted doesn't have any razor-specific code in it at all). Things like `$root.Name` are client side view models and view model properties, which you should be able to inspect with client side debugging such as Firebug. Perhaps you could extend your question a bit and elaborate on what you're exactly trying to do, maybe extend it with some JS code?

Comment: Yup,Some extend you're right.But My view model is in separate js file.I can debug those values when i am in javascript file with "script" enabled on firebug.But after executing that file,I need to check the final binding values on UI elements.So how can I do that ?I have attached a image also. Plz check that.